# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException after migrate from spring boot 1.5 to 2.0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Today I want to upgrade from spring boot 1.5.7 to 2.0.1 but at runtime spring cannot find any of my spring-beans that are outside of my ApplicationConfiguration class even if I mentioned these package on SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages) annotation.

These are the properties of the versions of my pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <springSecurity.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</springSecurity.version>
    <springBoot.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</springBoot.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.1</jackson.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.13</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

This is my ApplicationConfiguration class:

```
package t.i.config;    

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { 
    "t.i.DAO", 
    "t.i.SERVICES",
    "t.i.config"
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
    /*HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class*/ // old spring-boot 1.5 class
})
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.mssql.properties" })
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                  MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                  CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {

        ... code there that need MultiTenantConnectionProvider ...

    }
}
```

SessionFactory bean need MultiTenantConnectionProvider which exists in package t.i.config.multitenancy:

```
package t.i.config.multitenancy;

@Component
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

   ... code there ...

}
```

Despite the annotation on configuration class:

> @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "t.i.config")

Spring throw exception at runtime:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider' available

This is an exemple with MultiTenantConnectionProvider but spring does not found any of my beans (repositories and services) if they are not explicitly declared in ApplicationConfiguration file.

Maybe it is not important, but I launch my app as a jar and my class SpringBootApplicationLauncher handle commandlines parameters and context loading:

```
package t.i;

public class SpringBootApplicationLauncher {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication springApp = new SpringApplication(new Class[]{t.i.config.ApplicationConfiguration.class});
        context = springApp.run(args);
    }
}
```

Where I was wrong ? EDIT: It work thanks to Norbert Bicsi answer.

Comment: You are. really trying very hard to make things very complex and work around Spring Boot both in configuration and in the managed dependencies. What is the reason for using plain hibernate over JPA? What does it give you more then using JPA with Hibernate as the provider?

Comment: I using Hibernate session instead of JPA because I have started this project since 2 years and many queries was written in HQL (no JPQL). 
As I understand, some HQL features is not supported by JPQL, this is why I need Hibernate session to make HQL queries...

Comment: Depends on which queries you use. Nonetheless you still can use the plain `Session` when using JPA. Just unwrap it. That way you can let Spring Boot auto configure your hibernate and still have the code work with the legacy API. Basically the best of both worlds and you have a migration strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the basic approach where you leave you application class at the root level in your project so the `@SpringBootApplication` does a component scan of all the packages next to it and all subpackages.

Or you could try with the component scan annotation like:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "t.i.DAO", 
    "t.i.SERVICES",
    "t.i.config"
})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Spring can find my beans! But now I have another problem: 405 error on every http call

Comment: Be kind and upvote and accept my answer if it works :) And also make another question for the 405 error, I'm pretty sure I have a good idea what is up. I'll answer that too, just give some details, post the error and link the question here in the comments.

Comment: You are right! I am a beginner on stackoverflow, thanks again, I upvote your answer but I still not have 15 reputation so the upvote will not be visible now.

I posted my new problem there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739072/405-error-on-webservices-calls-after-migrating-spring-boot-1-5-to-2-0

Answer (score 2):

Since you are defining your own datasource in the multi-tenancy app, you cannot let Spring Boot do its magic of autoconfiguration of data sources and connection to databases as defined in the datasources properties.

You should be excluding the [DataSourceAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration.html) class.

So you need to add the exclude attribute as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

I have a recently created Spring Boot 2 (with Hibernate) and Spring Security 5 based database-per-tenant multitenancy web app with complete source code. [Take a look](https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2018/04/building-saas-style-multi-tenant-web.html) and let me know if it helps.