# 405 error on Webservices calls after migrating spring-boot 1.5 to 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, undertow

I am facing an unsolvable problem with my poor spring configuration knowledge: **every GET return error 404 and every POST return error 405**. 
My spring security filters work well but neither @PostMapping or @GetMapping annotated methods are getting called.
 I have taken care of rename old property **server.context-path** to new name **server.servlet.context-path** but it still not working.
I use undertow webserver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

My app.properties file is really named application.mssql.properties:

```
## Hibernate properties
... some properties ...

##Spring boot properties
server.servlet.context-path =/my-context
```

And this server instance configuration is in my ApplicationConfiguration:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { 
    "t.i.DAO", 
    "t.i.SERVICES",
    "t.i.config", 
    "t.i.config.security" })
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.mssql.properties" })
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    // Properties of application.mssql.properties file
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    ... some code there...

   @Bean
   public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory undertowServerInstance() { 
        UndertowServletWebServerFactory customizer = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
        customizer.addBuilderCustomizers((builder) -> {
            builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true);
        });

        // EDIT: add: set the context by reading app.properties
        customizer.setContextPath(env.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path"));
        return customizer;
   }
}
```

Notice that with my old spring 1.5 configuration, the method undertowServerInstance() was different:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer undertowServerInstance() {
    return (container) -> {
        if(container instanceof UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            ((UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                .addBuilderCustomizers(builder -> builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true));
        }
    };
}
```

I use a Spring security configuration class SecurityConfig like this:

package t.i.config;

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // allows AOP @PreAuthorize and some other annotations to be applied to methods.
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableScheduling // allows to run Spring schedulers and periodically run some tasks. We use scheduler for evicting EhCache tokens.
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        ... some code for security configuration ...

        // adding authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(this.authenticationManager), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

This class is used to generate a new token from user credentials or check token validity if it is present on header (this filter is called for every requests and it still work):

```
package t.i.config.security;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            // check or create token. Exception if credentials or token invalid
        }
        catch(AuthenticationException authenticationException){
            ((HttpServletResponse) http).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authenticationException.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is my WebMvcConfig which contain @RestController classes package location (edit: **added implements WebMvcConfigurer**) :

```
package t.i.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"t.i.controllers"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 ... code there ... 
}
```

And, for example, when I call `/api/authenticate` URL, my spring authentication filter method is called and token created but this WS is never called (returning 405 instead):

```
package t.i.controllers;

@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {


    @PostMapping("api/authenticate")
    public UserDTO authenticate(AuthenticationWithToken principal) {

        ... some code there that is never called with spring boot 2.0 ...

        return userDTO;
    }
}
```

I still don't understand this problem and I think something is missing in Undertow configuration.

EDIT: In the `ApplicationConfiguration.undertowServerInstance()` method, if I remove the line:

```
// EDIT: add: set the context by reading app.properties
customizer.setContextPath(env.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path"));
```

Then the AuthenticationFilter is not triggered any more. With spring boot 1.5 I never need to explicitly specify Undertow context.

EDIT: I changed my authentication WS method to GET:

```
 package t.i.CONTROLLERS;

@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserDTO authenticate(AuthenticationWithToken principal) {

        ... some code there that is still never called with spring boot 2.0 ...

        return userDTO;
    }
}
```

The authentication filter works well but method `AuthenticationController.authenticate` is still not called. This is that I got with chrome debugger:

[image: Error 404 with Get request authentication]

In summary:

- I have 404 error with get request and 405 with post
- Undertow need the context to be set explicitly otherwise my Authentication filter is not called

It's like spring does not handle any of my @RestController but they are still instanciated (I tested them with console print into constructor).

**EDIT:** It works now with spring boot 2.1.8.RELEASE! (I have no idea since which spring boot version it could be working because I switched from spring boot 1.5.7.RELEASE to 2.1.8.RELEASE)

Comment: how are you calling /api/atuthenticate? can you show as a request and its response?

Comment: I calling the right URL with a post request which contains user credentials, I will provide more details tomorrow (but before, with spring boot 1.5 it worked)

Answer (score 0):

You have your method mapped to a `POST` request and 405 means method not allowed.
That is because your are sending a GET request I assume.

Either change your mapping to `@GetMapping("api/authenticate")` or use a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send a POST request.

I would recommend the Postman approach, because it is a good idea to do things like auth wuth `POST` requests.

Comment: Of course but I use a complete web application that already exists and the Chrome debugger is able to see all the query details that I need. I just edited my post and trying with GET request.

Comment: Your call is going to `/my-context.api/authenticate`. Do you have `my-context` set up as the root context path?

Comment: I think yes: `my-context` is setted into my app.properties file:
   `server.servlet.context-path =/my-context`

Comment: Since you are getting 405 with post that means the url is actually mapped and you are just sending the wrong type of request. It is very strange that the get is not working since it clearly is on that path.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is taking your use of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` as an indication that it shouldn't auto-configure Spring MVC. Try replacing `extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport` with `implements WebMvcConfigurer` instead.

Comment: I change that but I still get post 405/get 404 error